# How to test and run Liferay portal using Selinium?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium2, test-management, test-automation-framework

I am new to testing, I have done the below steps. I don't know if I am correct or not.

1. Downloaded Selenium IDE and added it to Firefox.
2. Recorded tests and imported test cases as WebDriver/Junit.
3. Created a Java project, then a package, then created a class, then I copied the code from the imported test cases.
4. Added Selenium related jar files and then executed. It's working fine.

Now my questions are:

1. In Eclipse I have executed the tests they are working fine. What do I have to do to execute them on the production server?
2. Is Selenium WebDriver the best way to test?
3. How do I create test suites and how do I run them?
4. What are the steps to test in Chrome browser in Ubuntu 10.0.4?

Answer (score 2):

> 1.In eclipse i have executed the tests they are working fine, how i have to execute them in production server?

Your tests can run *in* every environment. You can have a Selenium Hub and many VMs with different operating systems and browsers. But for the beginning the tests can also run from your local computer.

You can choose *against* what environment (test environment, production) the test run. You can create a config file and set a property for that. Your testing framework can read this file and decide against what kind of environment the tests run. You can also work with Apache Maven, so you can use your tests with Jenkins and configure them.

You can start your test run *from* your local machine via eclipse or command line, if you choose Apache Maven. You also can have a Jenkins server and start the tests from there with a Jenkins job.

> 2.selinium Webdriver testing is best testing?

This depends on what exactly you want to test. If you want to test the GUI of web applications in different browsers and on different operating systems, Selenium 2 / WebDriver is an excellent open source tool for that.

> 3.how to create test suite and how to run them?

Selenium 2 / WebDriver on its own is no testing framework. It just control the browser. The testing framework is [JUnit](http://junit.org/). JUnit provide different ways to create test suites. You can create them with [Suites](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Aggregating-tests-in-suites) or [Categories](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Categories).

You can also use another testing framework like TestNG. But this are Java testing frameworks only. If you want to develop in another programming language, you have to choose another.

> 4.What are the steps to test in Chrome browser in Ubuntu 10.0.4 ?

You have to download the [Chrome Driver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver). For some browsers you need special drivers to control them. Not only for Google Chrome. Internet Explorer do also need one. Here is a  [Getting Started](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started) page.

---

Some other tips:

- Take a look into the [Selenium Wiki](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/w/list).
- Take a look into the [Selenium Documentation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/).
- Read the [Selenium Blog](http://seleniumhq.wordpress.com/) to keep up to date and particularly the A Smattering of Selenium posts for nice articles about how to get things work.